# Phrase for _CY_E

Tags: word, crosswords

I'm working on creating a crossword puzzle and am unfortunately stuck with the combination ~CY~E (blank C Y blank E). Does anyone have any PC phrases or words that could fit that combination?

Comment: Reminder: if one of these answers solved your question, mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 5):

Nothing [particularly likely](http://wordsolver.net/solve#!q=_CY_E&type=st_crossword&dic=d_twl&ml=15) - I'd try to change one of the crossing words instead.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I'm creating the puzzle but am stuck with that exact combination.

Comment: My response still applies though, which is to say there's nothing in reasonable English that will fit.

Comment: Your link helped though, it had a french word that was acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: scyðe, if you cheat and use OE letters. ;)

Comment: Glad you found something - and I heartily recommend sites like the one I linked; they're excellent for puzzle creation.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix -cyte means cell, so you could be cute and have it be ACYTE with the clue "Cell for sore eyes"

Answer (score 2):

Another cryptic:

> RCYBE

Rotate the string:

> CYBER

Answer (score 1):

Instructing someone to freeze ('icy be'), or saying one is frozen ("Icy me")?

If the puzzle is using cryptics, perhaps an abbreviated institution got mixed up with a yes-man (ACYOE interleaves "CO" and "AYE")?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use those letters, I think you're going to have to settle for obscure words.

It's poor form, but you could use

After shuffling, my ace let me get ahead (1, 4)

> anag. MYACE = A CYME
>  a head (of unexpanded leaves) = a [cyme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyme)

Answer (score 1):

**Ocyte** is a less common spelling for oocyte - egg cell.
Would that work?